# How to change temporary directory for pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, dump

I'm running out of space from my hard drive which has a 18GB PostgreSQL database.
When I try `pg_dump` to a different drive, PostgreSQL creates temporary files on the disk it's dumping from, so I run out of space and the dump fails.

I tried [this from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18731265/720077) and a small file is created in the new directory, but nothing else, and `pg_dump` still writes to the original disk.

How do I change temp directory for `pg_dump`?

Note: My `work_mem` setting is pretty high already, I can't change that.
My db version is 9.0.13.

Comment: Can you mount the temp dir (is it `/tmp`?) on an other disk?

Comment: Yes, I could put it to another disk, but don't know how to safely do that?

Comment: How are you invoking pg_dump?  Where is the temp file, what is it called?

Comment: `pg_dump -U myusername 'database' --format=tar | gzip > /anotherdrive/filetodump.tar.gz`  
What temp file is where?

Comment: I guess that is the temp file that `gzip` uses, not one from `pg_dump`

Comment: `pg_dump -U myusername 'database' --format=tar > /anotherdrive/filetodump.tar` eats free space the same way as with gzip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The temporary files are a side effect of the [`--format=tar` option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html).

A backup in default plain format goes through without temporary tables in the local drive. Omit the option to produce a backup in plain format without temporary local files.